# Synchronize data b/w two data stores

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have two different databases, one's an old legacy one which I'll be decommissioning due to the old service not being used anymore. The other one's is a new service and will eventually replace the old system. Before that happens we need both services running for a while.

Both have two tables for users for storing the email address, password and the other table is for simple user related data (addresses.)

I need to synchronize data between these two databases. The old one is a MS SQL Server DB and the new one's a NoSQL DB, (DynamoDB.)

My strategy would be that before going live, copy all the users from the old DB to the new one and then once the new system is running then synchronize the users between each DB.

I'll do this by having a tool run periodically to check any users added after last run by querying the users table something like this `WHERE CreationDate >= LastRunTime` and then for each user query it if it exists in the other database. I'll do this two way i.e. from old DB -> new DB and from new DB -> old DB.

Is this a good way of doing this? Any other better, fast solutions to achieve this?

How can I detect changes to existing user's data? Is there any better solution than checking & matching every user's record in both systems' tables and then taking the one that's last modified (by checking at the LastModifiedDate timestamp for each record) and updating it in the other system's table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1** **(My Recommended):** Whenever system insert/update a record in either of the databases you add/update a record data in the database and add that information in a `Queue`.

A sperate reader will read from the queue and replicate the data to respective database periodically this way your data will get sync between the databases.

**Note**: Another advantage of using the queue would be that you don't have to set very high throughput in your DynamoDB table.

**Solution 2:** What you had suggested in your question, you can add a CRON job that will replicate the databases by checking the record based on timestamp.

Comment: What happens if it fails to write to the queue? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 You just need to have a mechanism that will say writing in the queue is failed, so repeat the last process.

Comment: I assume that I would have two queues i.e. SQL queue and NoSQL queue.  If the application is unable to write to one of the queues then it fails to write to both.  Is that right? Is that what is meant by a transactional message (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms704006(v=vs.85).aspx)? +1.

Comment: Thanks.  Is that how you would approach it or is there another approach?

Comment: Another approach would be to handle this at application level manually but I guess the 1st option is better.

Comment: With regards to your solution 1 - what happens if a record is written to the SQL database, however it fails to write to the NoSQL queue.  Can these two operations be treated as one atomic unit that either succeeds or fails?

Comment: No, it cant. but again as I have mentioned in the previous comment we need to have an application logic which will notify that adding operation to a queue is failed thus perform this operation again or roll back from SQL as well. Make sense?

Comment: I think that does cater for one scenario.  However, what happens if an operation is added to the nosql queue, however the sql database is unable to commit the transaction for some reason? Thanks again.  I am almost there.

Comment: Same thing, redo the operation on sql from queue

Comment: Would you have a separate process that processes messages in the read store queue (in the order they were added to the queue) and a separate process that processes messages in the write store queue (in the order they were added to the queue)? Is this approach suitable for a banking application? Last question.

Comment: Yes the process should be separate, but for the banking application, I guess we need something more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I've executed several table migrations from Oracle / MySQL to DynamoDB with no downtime and the approach I used was a little different than what you described.  This approach ends up requiring more coding but I would consider it a lower risk approach than the hard cutover you described.

This approach requires multiple phases as described below:

**Phase 1**

- Create the new DynamoDB table(s) for the data in your legacy system.

**Phase 2**

- Update your application to write/update data in both the legacy database and in DynamoDB. Your application will still read and write to the legacy system so this should be a low risk change.
- Immediately before deploying this code load DynamoDB up with all of the old data.
- Immediately after deploying audit the database to make sure they are in sync.

**Phase 3**

- Update your application to start reading from DynamoDB.  This should be low risk because your application will have been maintaining data in DynamoDB for some time.
- Keep your application writing to the legacy database so you can cut back if you identify any problems in the new implementation.  This ensures the cutover is low risk and you can easily roll back.

**Phase 4**

- Remove the code from your application that reads and writes to the legacy database and deploy this to production.
- You can now decommission the legacy database!

This is definitely more steps and will take more time than just taking the application down, migrating all of the data, and then deploying a new version of the application to read/write from DynamoDB.  However, the main benefit to this approach is that it not only requires no downtime but is lower risk as it tests the change in phases and allows for easy rollback if any issues are encountered.

Answer (score 0):

On high level, a sync job could be 1> cron job based or 2> notification based.

The cron job could do sync as well as auditing if you have "creation time" and "last_updated_by time". In this case the master DB (from where the data should be synced from) is normally a SQL Db since it's much easier to do table scan in SQL than in NoSQL (like in DynamoDB you need to use its scan function and it's limited by the table's hash key).

The second option is to build a notification machenism and this could be based on DynamoDB's stream http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html. It's a mature feature for DynamoDB, it guarantees event order and could achieve near real time event deliver. What you need to do is to build a listen for those events.

Lastly, you could take a look at AWS Database Migration Service https://aws.amazon.com/dms/ to see if it satisfies your requirement.